# How Do I Run A Script On A Specific Wepbage Using A Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a script that I would like to run on a specific page. How would I go about doing this using a Google Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`manifest.json`

```
{
"name": "",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
   "js": ["script.js"]
}],
 "permissions": [
  "http://example.com/*",
  "tabs"
 ]
}
```

With that manifest, on the page `http://example.com/*`, the `script.js` file will be included. Read the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) please, before asking a question.